# Add a new menu section in admin page in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have created a `content type`, now I want to have a section menu in admin page to have specific links for this `content type`. I want it include New link and content item list for this `content type`.

How can i achieve this? preferably with no editing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without code, at the same time you will need a small code chunk to achieve this, like the following code:

```
public class AdminMenu : INavigationProvider {
    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public string MenuName {
        get { return "admin"; }
    }

    public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder) {
        builder
            .Add(T("Your Content Type Display Name"), "1", menu => menu
                .Action("List", "Admin", new { area = "Contents", id = "YourContentTypeName" }));
    }
}
```